# TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined for $location.search()

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the below param in the params: list below. I am getting the below error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
    at Object.async (abcd.html?kId=pqr)
```

url:

```
http://localhost:8080/.........../abcd.html?kId=pqr
```

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('angModule', [], function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
app.factory(
    'myService',
    function($http,$location) {
        return {
            async : function() {
                return $http
                    .get('http://localhost:8080/...........,,,,./...',{params:{"kId": $location.search()['kId'] }});
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: I don't see `$location.search()` in the shared code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not defining the service correctly, that's why `$location` is undefined. You have to use notation:

```
batchModule.factory('myService', ['$interval', '$log', function($interval, $log) {
```

See "Dependencies" section in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. In you case that would be:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {
    // ...
}]);
```

Comment: Actually he doesn't have to use notation. That should solve production minifications issues. For all we know he's using a task to do that in build time.

Comment: Yea that notation is only needed if you minify your code. Angular provides you with named parameters (only for its injectable things so controllers, services etc), thats how its injection works. However minifying your code renames all your function arguments thus breaking all your dependencies. the array allows you to essentially alias them so minifying doesn't break things.